# cannot get index of column selected/clicked in DT package for shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to make a basic program in R shiny framework so that I can display an interactive data table. The basic function I need to perform but can't is getting the row and column index of any selected/clicked cell. I have done research online and followed the tutorials exactly, but what is shown in the tutorials does not appear to be working. Since I think getting clicks is harder, I have settled with getting the row and column index of whatever cell is selected. Here is what I currently have for the ui.R and server.R files:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTable)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  lastTransToMat = data.table(cbind(c(.5,.5),c(.8,.2)))
  output$transtable = DT::renderDataTable(lastTransToMat,options = list(target = 'column+row'))

  output$response <-DT::renderDataTable({
    rows= as.numeric(input$transtable_rows_selected)
    cols = as.numeric(input$transtable_columns_selected)

    print(rows)
    print(cols)

    response = data.table(cbind(c(paste0("rows: ",rows),c(paste0("cols: " ,cols)))))
    print(response)
    return(response)

  })
}

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("transition table"),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('transtable'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('response')
    )
))
```

When I runApp() on this, I am only able to get the index of the row, but not the index of the column. See output below:

```
numeric(0)
        V1
1: rows: 1
2:  cols:
```

There is a similar data.table output in the shiny app itself.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

How can I get both the row and column index of a selection? And what about clicks?

Best,

Paul

EDIT:

As per user5029763's suggestion, I replaced my server.R function with the following:

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
library(shinyTable)
library(DT)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("transition table"),
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput('transtable'),
    DT::dataTableOutput('response'),
    htmlOutput('response2')
  )
))

#server.R
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  lastTransToMat = data.table(cbind(c(.5,.5),c(.8,.2)))
  output$transtable = DT::renderDataTable(lastTransToMat,server = F,options = list(target = 'cell'))

  output$response <-DT::renderDataTable({
    cell= as.numeric(input$transtable_cell_clicked)
    print(cell)
    response = data.table(cbind(c(paste0("cell: "),c(paste0(cell)))))
    print(response)
    return(response)

  })

  output$response2 <- renderUI({
    cells <- input$transtable_cell_clicked
    if(length(cells) == 0) return( div('No cell is selected') )
    cells <- data.frame(cells)[-3]
    response <- paste0(c('Row', 'Column'), ': ', cells, collapse = ' / ')
    div(response)
  })
}
```

Output before any click:

[image: before]

Output after click/selection:
[image]

Is this the same as the output you get when you runApp() on this?

EDIT: Also just FYI, I tried this on another computer with the most updated version of R and got the same output, so I don't think it has to do with my version/computer.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to get the index of clicked cells you could go with:

```
  output$transtable = DT::renderDataTable(
      lastTransToMat, 
      server = F,
      selection = list(target = 'cell')
  )
```

Then, `input$transtable_cell_clicked` will be a list with row/column index and the value within the cell. Just remember that the column index starts at 0.

EDIT: one way to print out

#server.R

```
output$response2 <- renderUI({
  cells <- input$transtable_cell_clicked
  if(length(cells) == 0) return( div('No cell is selected') )
  cells <- data.frame(cells)[-3]
  response <- paste0(c('Row', 'Column'), ': ', cells, collapse = ' / ')
  div(response)
})
```

#ui.R

```
htmlOutput('response2')
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but I am not getting the expected output. Please see my edit.

Comment: The problem is how you are manipulating `input$transtable_cell_clicked`. I don't quite understand what you are doing at `response`. Do you have to put them in a table or printing them out on the app would suffice?

Comment: I am just trying to print it out at this point. What is wrong with the way I am manipulating input$transtable_cell_clicked? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I just tried the code you posted on the edit. The `response` table is empty at the beggining bacause no cell is selected. But once you select a cell, the info is placed at the table. I'll edit mu answer with another way to print the response at the app as a string.

Comment: I still don't see any output using that code. Is there something wrong with my package? Why would it only be outputting the row selected, but not the column celected or the cell clicked? PLease see my edit for the full updated code I am using.

Comment: hum... what version of the DT package do you have? I think cell selection is still only on the dev-version...

Comment: yes, that was it! I installed the dev version using install_github("rstudio/DT"), and the new version worked as expected. thank you!